# Is there an easier ways to position JFrame Components in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout, layout-manager

i'm using eclipse
I'm a little new to java .. i made a Button, a TextField and a label and put them into a JPanel - then put the JPanel on the JFrame ..

it was really hard to position them correctly because i had to change x, y, width, height for all three of them and if it wasn't at where it should be i had to change x,y and compile&run and do it all over again until it's at the correct position ..
is there an easier way to position those things or a software to generate the coordinates for me?

Sorry for my english

Comment: See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I'd take a step back and check out basic Swing functionality before going too much further. Or consider using a GUI interface builder--I don't recall what (or if) Eclipse uses for that anymore.

Comment: In the NetBeans IDE it is no problem. With eclipse I do not do Swing.

Comment: I can make something in Adobe flash right now to add and move objects and output the coordinates but i'm sure that some one made it before (right?)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Layout Manager.

For example:

> BorderLayout
>
> [image]
>
> A picture of a GUI that uses BorderLayout Every content pane is
> initialized to use a BorderLayout. (As Using Top-Level Containers
> explains, the content pane is the main container in all frames,
> applets, and dialogs.) A BorderLayout places components in up to five
> areas: top, bottom, left, right, and center. All extra space is placed
> in the center area. Tool bars that are created using JToolBar must be
> created within a BorderLayout container, if you want to be able to
> drag and drop the bars away from their starting positions. For further
> details, see How to Use BorderLayout.

```
...//Container pane = aFrame.getContentPane()...
JButton button = new JButton("Button 1 (PAGE_START)");
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

//Make the center component big, since that's the
//typical usage of BorderLayout.
button = new JButton("Button 2 (CENTER)");
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

button = new JButton("Button 3 (LINE_START)");
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4 (PAGE_END)");
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

button = new JButton("5 (LINE_END)");
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Have a look at the complete docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: try to explain how to use layouts - show, how easy components can be added and arragned, that would increase the quality of your answer dramatically!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a GUI design tool called [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). Depending on which package of Eclipse you have, it might already be installed. If not, you can easily add it to your Eclipse installation.

As some comments mentioned, you should first learn more about AWT and Swing and how they handle layout of components. The gist of it is to *not* use absolute positioning of components, instead [use LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).